# Apache POI Excel sheet: resize a picture while keeping its ratio

Tags: java, excel, image, apache-poi

Hello I have created excel sheet by using POI. I've added picture(jpg-file) in the next way:

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
//...
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("img.jpg");
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
int picIdx = wb.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
anchor.setCol1(5);
anchor.setRow1(5);
Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, picIdx);
pict.resize();
```

Now I want the picture to fit into that cell, but i don't want to change its aspect ratio. the scales i can put into resize are in respect to the cell, which obviously can have a different ratio. I tried to calculate the scales but the problem is, that I can't get or set the row height in pixel, only in pt and i can't compute the cells ratio either bc the i can't get width and height in the same unit... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

There is a [Units](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/util/Units.html) class in POI, which provide convertion between pixel and point.
And here are some methods might be helpful to set cell's width and height.

**1.Centimeters to Pixels**

```java
public static int cmToPx(double cm) {
    return (int) Math.round(cm * 96 / 2.54D);
}
```

`96` is my Monitor's DPI (check yours from [dpilove](http://dpi.lv/))
and 1 inch = 2.54 centimeters

**2.Centimeters to RowHeight**

```java
public static int cmToH(double cm) {
    return (int) (Units.pixelToPoints(cmToPx(cm)) * 20); //POI's Units
}
```

Usage: `sheet.setDefaultRowHeight(cmToH(1.0))`
Reference: [HSSFRow#getHeightInPoints](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html#getHeightInPoints--)

> Set the height in "twips" or 1/20th of a point.

**3.Centimeters to ColumnWidth**

```java
public static int cmToW(double cm) {
    return (int) Math.round(((cmToPx(cm) - 5.0D) / 8 * 7 + 5) / 7 * 256);
}
```

Usage: `sheet.setColumnWidth(cmToW(1.0))`
Use `(px - 5.0D) / 8` to convert from pixels to points in excel width.(When drag column's width in excel, pixels and points will show around your cursor)
Reference: [HSSFSheet#setColumnWidth](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#setColumnWidth-int-int-)

> Set the width (**in units of 1/256th of a character width**)
>
> Excel uses the following formula (Section 3.3.1.12 of the OOXML spec):

```
// Excel width, not character width
width = Truncate([{Number of Visible Characters} * {Maximum Digit Width} + {5 pixel padding}]/{Maximum Digit Width} * 256) / 256
```

> Using the Calibri font as an example, the maximum digit width of 11 point font size is 7 pixels (at 96 dpi). If you set a column width to be eight characters wide, e.g. setColumnWidth(columnIndex, 8*256), then the actual value of visible characters (the value shown in Excel) is derived from the following equation:

```
Truncate([numChars * 7 + 5] / 7 * 256) / 256 = 8;
```

---

Use XSSFClientAnchor to resize a picture to fill the cell and keep its ratio:

```java
// set padding between picture and gridlines so gridlines would not covered by the picture
private static final double PADDING_SIZE = 10;
private static final int PADDING = Units.toEMU(PADDING_SIZE);

/**
 * Draw Image inside specific cell
 *
 * @param wb workbook
 * @param sheet sheet
 * @param cellW cell width in pixels
 * @param cellH cell height in pixels
 * @param imgPath image path
 * @param col the column (0 based) of the first cell.
 * @param row the row (0 based) of the first cell.
 * @param colSize the column size of cell
 * @param rowSize the row size of cell
 */
public static void drawImageInCell(SXSSFWorkbook wb, SXSSFSheet sheet, int cellW, int cellH,
      String imgPath, int col, int row, int colSize, int rowSize) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get(imgPath);
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(path.toFile());
    int[] anchorArray = calCellAnchor(Units.pixelToPoints(cellW), Units.pixelToPoints(cellH),
       img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
    XSSFClientAnchor anchor = new XSSFClientAnchor(anchorArray[0], anchorArray[1], anchorArray[2],
        anchorArray[3], (short) col, row, (short) (col + colSize), row + rowSize);
    int index = wb.addPicture(Files.readAllBytes(path), XSSFWorkbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
    sheet.createDrawingPatriarch().createPicture(anchor, index);
}

/**
 * calculate POI cell anchor
 *
 * @param cellX cell width in excel points
 * @param cellY cell height in excel points
 * @param imgX image width
 * @param imgY image height
 */
public static int[] calCellAnchor(double cellX, double cellY, int imgX, int imgY) {
    // assume Y has fixed padding first
    return calCoordinate(true, cellX, cellY, imgX, imgY);
}

/**
 * calculate cell coordinate
 *
 * @param fixTop is Y has fixed padding
 */
private static int[] calCoordinate(boolean fixTop, double cellX, double cellY, int imgX, int imgY) {
    double ratio = ((double) imgX) / imgY;
    int x = (int) Math.round(Units.toEMU(cellY - 2 * PADDING_SIZE) * ratio);
    x = (Units.toEMU(cellX) - x) / 2;
    if (x < PADDING) {
        return calCoordinate(false, cellY, cellX, imgY, imgX);
    }
    return calDirection(fixTop, x);
}

/**
 * calculate X's direction
 *
 * @param fixTop is Y has fixed padding
 * @param x X's padding
 */
private static int[] calDirection(boolean fixTop, int x) {
    if (fixTop) {
        return new int[] { x, PADDING, -x, -PADDING };
    } else {
        return new int[] { PADDING, x, -PADDING, -x };
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `cellW` and `cellH`?

Comment: @barfuin cell width and height in pixels. Added an example in the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Base64 image data and I do it like this, for me it adds at given col/row and resizes it properly, also I dont want to to fit the cell it can axpand to whatever to right and bottom:

```
    byte[] imageBase64Data = base64DataString.getBytes();
    byte[] imageRawData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(imageBase64Data);

    int imgWidth = 1920; // only initial if not known
    int imgHeight = 1080; // only initial if not known

    try {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageRawData));
        imgWidth = img.getWidth();
        imgHeight = img.getHeight();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(imageRawData, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);

    CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
    Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();

    anchor.setCol1(desiredCol);
    anchor.setRow1(desiredRow);
    Picture picture = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
    picture.resize(0.7 * imgWidth / XSSFShape.PIXEL_DPI, 5 * imgHeight / XSSFShape.PIXEL_DPI);
```

Comment: This doesnt work for poi 4.1.0, the image has wrong aspect ratio. What are the 0.7 and 5 constants?